# Combinatorics and anagrams

Tags: combinatorics

I've just starting learning about combinatorics, and I know that for the word COMBINATORICS, there are $\frac{13!}{2!\cdot2!\cdot2!}$ possible anagrams, but **how many such anagrams neither begin nor end with the letter C**?

I first found possible permutations of the remaining 11 letters which is $\frac{11!}{2!\cdot2!}$.

Then I know there are $10\times11$ ways to insert the two Cs into the 11-letter word. So the final result is $\frac{11!}{2!\cdot2!}\times10\times11\div2$.

Is my way of reasoning correct? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, but there aren't $110$ ways to insert the Cs, there are only $55$ (I think you meant this since you included a $\div 2$ in your final answer.

---

We should first deal with the restricted letters: the two Cs. There are $11$ spots for the two Cs, so there are $$\binom{11}{2}=\frac{11\cdot 10}{2}=55$$ ways to place them. This is a [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

Now, there are $11$ other letters and $11$ other spots, with $2$ letters appearing twice. You correctly noted that there were $$\frac{11!}{2!\cdot 2!}$$ ways to arrange these remaining letters.

This gives a final answer of $$55 \cdot \frac{11!}{4}= \boxed{548,856,000}$$

Answer (score 1):

Compute how many there are in all.

Compute how many have a C at the beginning or at the end (they should be the same). Add this. Compute how many have C at beginning *and* end (you counted them twice in the above), subtract from the previous number.

This is the number of anagrams with C at beginning or end, this you subtract from the first number.